# Education questions on Mathematics SE

Tags: discussion

A few times lately I've noticed questions like this one coming up om Mathematics SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086468/result-of-multiplication-having-zeroes-after-the-decimal

Despite the mathematical title, this really seems to be a question about what to teach primary school children about multiplying decimals and about significant figures and rounding. As such, I'd expect the best answers to be given by teachers  who are aware of what children that age are likely to understand, what misconceptions they could accidentally learn and how to avoid them, and so on.

Occasionally I leave a comment like "You could try asking about this on Mathematics Educators SE", but I've not seen anyone take it up.

I'm not sure how to boil this down to a specific question. I suppose I'm asking whether to keep on trying to direct askers of questions with a strong education element here, and asking what else might be done to make it more likely that someone whose question could be well-answered  here actually comes here to ask.

Comment: In my experience, when a question about mathematics education comes up in Mathematics Stack Exchange and I direct the OP to consider asking it here at Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange, around half of the time they do.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Maybe I'll do it a bit more, then, and be a bit more definite about it! Thanks.

Comment: I guess if you have enough rep on MSE you could suggest to migrate - I'm not exactly sure how that process works, though.  (But it would seem very logical, as MO stuff gets migrated to MSE all the time.)

Comment: What, exactly, is the question, here?  I reads like a lamentation only.